# On change radio button state show submit button... how?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a submit button only when the radio button value change. I will have several radio groups and the button should appear if any radio button change! Also, if radio button group value gets to default value submit button will hide again.

```
$("form :radio").live('change',function(){

});
```

My new code:

```
//hide the submit button on load
        $('form :submit').hide();

        //Data structure where the initial value from radio button(s) will be stored
        var dbRadios = [];

        //Getting the initial values from the radio button(s) and load them to the data structure
        $("form :radio:checked").each(function() {
            dbRadios.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });


        //Attach onclick event to radio button(s)
        $('form :radio').click(function() {

            //The event fired, therefore the "New value(s)" (radio button value(s))  will be stored in the data sctructure
            var submitedRadios = [];

            //Geting the values from checked radio buttons
            $("form :radio:checked").each(function() {
                submitedRadios.push($(this).attr('value'));
            });

            //Now comparing both data structures
            if(dbRadios.compare(submitedRadios)){
                $('form :submit').fadeOut('slow');
            }else{
                $('form :submit').fadeIn('slow', function(){ ACTION! WILL BE EXECUTED MANY TIMES AS BUTTONS CLICKED});
            }

        });


        $("form").submit(function () {
        //AJAX GOES HERE!   
        alert("a submeter dados");  
        })
```

The compare function:

```
//Compare two different arrays
    Array.prototype.compare = function(testArr) {
        if (this.length != testArr.length) return false;
        for (var i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
        if (this[i].compare) { 
            if (!this[i].compare(testArr[i])) return false;
        }
        if (this[i] !== testArr[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works great!

```
//Attach onclick event to radio button(s)
        $('form :radio').click(function() {
            //Every new event clears the array so the new values can be stored properly
            submitedRadios = [];
            //Geting the values from checked radio buttons every time the state modifies
            $("form :radio:checked").each(function() {
                submitedRadios.push($(this).attr('value'));
            });

            //Now comparing both data structures, if equal submit button hides, else shows
            if(dbRadios.compare(submitedRadios)){
                $('form :submit').fadeOut('slow');
            }else{
                $('form :submit').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like the following. You can write more specific logics to meet your requirements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   //hide the submit button on load
   $('form :submit').hide();

   var defaultVal = 'default';

   //attach onchange event to radio buttons
   $('form :radio').change(function() {
       var val = $(this).val();

       if(val!=defaultVal) {
         $('form :submit').show();
       } else {
         $('form :submit').hide();
       }
   });

});
```

The code above will show/hide submit button based on the current value of the clicked/changed radio button.

Comment: the above code will hide the button but doesn't responde to radio events... thank you :)

Comment: please check it now. there was error in the code I had used $('input :submit') in the place of $('form :submit'). thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: check my new code, your code is showing the the button but ain't hide it at least in my code which has lot's of radio button groups...

Comment: So you are creating an array of default values and comparing it.But may I know the working of `dbRadios.compare(submitedRadios)`? I am not able to run this at my end.

Comment: Anyway there is a problem, if you get something like two or three radio groups then it will attach the click() event on each button. And that can be a problem because I will get as many actions as clicked buttons; an example can be: (see code above " //Now comparing both data structures ")

Answer (score 0):

you could try binding an onclick with logic inside the onclick to see if its different

Comment: How is that made? Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: i "answered" his question... and commented on my own answer that someone had a more complete version, not sure how this isnt an answer